# Creating unique user results in this error IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the above error raised on the line

`user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)`

even though the username is unique and when I check in the `admin` page the user is being created. I did extend the Django `User` model with the below code as I want users to have additional Location info:

`models.py`:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default="")
```

I'm not sure why the error is being raised even though the user is being created. Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings? If it's a custom model, could you provide the code?

Comment: @mastazi: So it isn't actually set to anything and it is not a custom model; I changed the `OneToOneField` relationship to `User` and still the same error. I'm new to Django and any thoughts on what might be going on would be appreciated. The db is SQLite.